# Convolution of two non-independent probability distributions (Exponential, Uniform)

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

I want to describe a probability distribution which — what I believe — is a convolution between two *dependent* (rather than two independent) probability distributions.

In many ways [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439969/finding-convolution-of-exponential-and-uniform-distribution-how-to-set-integral) is very similar to mine, although my situation is more generic/general: I have an exponential distribution with rate $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ (i.e., mean $\lambda$) and a uniform distribution on $[a,b]$ (where $a>0$ and $a<b$), and I am trying to find the combined general distribution. However, my problem is the exponential distribution should be dependent on the result of the uniform distribution... at least, that's what I believe is needed to describe the situation where I generate a uniform random variable and sum it with a exponential random variable (I may not be describing this correctly; I am trying to define the general distribution describing the total time between two "back-to-back"/sequential, stochastic events whose rates can be described by the distributions above).

In more mathematical terms, I am dealing with the functions:

$\mathbf{\\ f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{\lambda} e^{-\frac{x}{\lambda}} & x\geq 0\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}}
\ \hspace{20pt} \
\mathbf{f_Y(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a} & a\leq x\leq b\\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} 
\end{cases}}$

...and I am looking for the result $(f_X*f_Y)(x)$ without knowledge of these functions being independent.

---

My understanding about convolutions is extremely elementary: I roughly understand what they are, what purpose(s) they serve, and to some degree how they are built, but I struggle to define them with respect to functions with complex domains — especially for situations involving dependent probability distributions. As in, I know that:

$(f_X*f_Y)(x) = f_Z(z) = \int_{x = -\infty}^\infty f_{XY}(x,z-x) \, dx$ if $Z=X+Y$

...but we should not be able to apply the standard approach of $f_Z(z) = \int_{x = -\infty}^\infty f_X(x) \, f_Y(z-x) \, dx$ since we *may* not be able to say $f_{XY}(x,z-x)=f_X(x) \, f_Y(z-x)$ (I only say '*may*' because I truly have no idea how independence or dependence affects the convolution of probability distributions).

I have some idea that the domain of $f_Z(z)$ is $[a,\infty)$ provided $a>0$ (or, at least, *should be* — based on what I understand to be true about the general distribution needed to describe my situation), but I have no understanding on how to go any further with — or without — this information.

Comment: What is the exact relation between $X$ and $Y$? It is not clear in what sense they are dependent. In principle, in this case I would use the PDF method, of $F_Z(t)=P(Z\leq t)=P(X+Y\leq t)$ and computing this probability using a double integral over $f_{XY}$ in the domain where $X+Y\leq t$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe them in the proper context of probabilities, but from what I *do* understand about the relationship is that I perform some task for $X$ hours, then perform a similar task with the same resources for $Y$ hours; I am therefore trying to describe the total anticipated time, i.e., $X+Y$ hours, as a general distribution function for a given resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** *I'm not too sure if this is correct since it is somewhat "convoluted" (pun intended) and contrived, but this is the best I could scrap together with my understanding.*

---

I tried to take advantage of the properties of the Laplace transform to derive a "backwards approach" at solving the convolution problem via inversion.

Namely, let it be said that if $f_X, f_Y$ have well-defined Laplace transforms $\mathcal{L}[f_X],\mathcal{L}[f_Y]$, then

$
(1)\,
\mathcal{L}[f_X*f_Y]=\mathcal{L}[f_X]\mathcal{L}[f_Y].
$

...so a good first step is to work out the Laplace transforms of the individual functions, then perform a simple product.

For $f_X$,
$
(2)\,
\mathcal{L}[f_X](s)=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}f_X(t) \, dt=\frac{1}{\lambda s + 1}.
$

...and for $f_Y$,
$
(3)\,
\mathcal{L}[f_Y](s)=\int_{a}^{b} e^{-st}f_Y(t) \, dt=\frac{e^{-as}-e^{-bs}}{(b-a)s}.
$*

Now, it's only a matter of finding the product, which is rather easy:

$
(4)\,
\mathcal{L}[f_X]\mathcal{L}[f_Y]=\frac{e^{-as}-e^{-bs}}{(b-a)s(\lambda s + 1)}.
$

But, $(4)$ isn't $f_X*f_Y$; it's $\mathcal{L}[f_X*f_Y]$ (according to $(1)$). So, how do we get $f_X*f_Y$ from $(4)$? Using the inverse Laplace transform! Using indicator functions where needed, we have:

$
(5)\,
\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}[\frac{e^{-as}-e^{-bs}}{(b-a)s(\lambda s + 1)}](x)=\frac{1}{b-a}[\mathbb{1}(x-a\geq0)(1-e^{(a-x)/\lambda})+\mathbb{1}(x-b\geq0)(e^{(b-x)/\lambda}-1)].
$

Taking it all together,

$
(f_X*f_Y)(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a}[1-e^{(a-x)/{\lambda}}] & a \leq  x \leq b & \\ 
\frac{1}{b-a}e^{(a-x)/\lambda}[e^{(b-a)/\lambda}-1] & x > b & \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} & 
\end{cases}
$

...given $b>a$ and $\lambda> 0$.

This seems to agree with the expected solution given in the question I referred to and strongly agrees with the domain I need for $f_Z(x)$ (i.e., $x\in[a,\infty)$), which suggests that I was wrong to assume that $f_X$ and $f_Y$ were non-independent/dependent (this was certainly due to my poor understanding on the criteria necessary for dependence between probability distributions).

---

*<sub>*This is where it feels like I'm hand-waving a certain detail about Laplace transforms, so I'm a bit unsure if the limits are practical; it makes sense for the domain of* $f_Y$*, but I'm not entirely certain that I can arbitrarily restrict the limits of integration to this domain when deriving Laplace transforms.*</sub>